# Highlighting a Table Correctly Despite rowspan and colspan attributes - WITHOUT jQuery

Tags: javascript

Thanks to some !#$#@ in another department who wrote some crap code, I am unable to use the jQuery library - despite my fervent desire to do so.  Their software has already been released into the world, and I have to be compatible.

============================================

I am trying to highlight a table.  Desired behavior:

1. Clicking on a cell in the body highlights the row.
2. Clicking on a cell in the head highlights the column.
3. If a column and row are both highlighted, the intersection is highlighted a different color (super-highlight).
4. Clicking on a previously super-highlighted cell turns off the highlights.

This behavior is simple enough to do with a basic table, but when rowspans and colspans start rearing their ugly heads, things start to get a little wonky... highlighting cell[5], for instance, no longer works reliably.

My thought, in order to speed execution time of the highlighting itself (by changing a class name), is to pre-calculate the 'offsets' of all cells - with a 'colStart' and 'colEnd', 'rowStart' and 'rowEnd' when the page loads and store that in an array somehow.

The question:  How would YOU implement this functionality?  I am fairly rusty at my JavaScript, awfully rudimentary in my programming skills and would benefit greatly from some guidance.

Thanks,

Scott.

Answer (score 0):

If the reasons for not being able to use jQuery are technical (e.g. someone's used $ for something silly), you could try jQuery's `noConflict` mode.  Just wanted you to be aware of that =)

Your precalculation system seems like it'd work to me, otherwise.

Comment: nah, it's not a conflict with another library - their code breaks jQuery somehow, and I can't determine how without their source code, which I'm not privy to.

Answer (score 0):

I made a script that detects headers and sub-headers with colspans, but without rowspans in the table rows:

```
jQuery('#yourTable tbody td').bind('click',function(e) {
var tr = jQuery(e.target).parent('tr');
var y = parseInt(jQuery('tr', this).index(tr));
var x = parseInt(tr.children('td').index(jQuery(e.target)));
var jTdFecha = tr.find('td:first');
var sFecha = jTdFecha.text();
var arrCeldas = {};
var arrEncabezados = {};
var arrJFila = {};
var nTemp = 0;
var jTdEncabezadoFecha,nCantCabeceras,jTemp, nI, nJ, nK, nL, bTemp;

arrJFila[1]={
    'arrHijos' : jQuery('#yourTable tbody tr:first-child')
};
jTdEncabezadoFecha = arrJFila[1]['arrHijos'].find('td:first');
nCantCabeceras = jTdEncabezadoFecha.attr('rowspan');
for(nI=1;nI<=nCantCabeceras;nI++){
    if(nI>1){
        arrJFila[nI]={
            'arrHijos'  : arrJFila[nI-1]['arrHijos'].next()
        };
    }
    arrCeldas[nI] = {
        'arrHijos'      : arrJFila[nI]['arrHijos'].children(),
        'arrColspan'    : {},
        'arrRowspan'    : {},
        'nCant'         : '',
        'arrLastIndex'  : {},
        'arrLastSavedColspan': {},
        'arrLastColspan': {}
    };
    for(nJ=0;nJ<=nCantCabeceras;nJ++){
        arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastIndex'][nJ] = 0;
        arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][nJ] = 0;
        arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastSavedColspan'][nJ] = 0;
    }
}
for(nI=1;nI<=nCantCabeceras;nI++){
    arrCeldas[nI]['nCant'] = arrCeldas[nI]['arrHijos'].length;
    nTemp = 0;
    for(nJ=0;nJ<arrCeldas[nI]['nCant'];nJ++){ //Recorremos todas las celdas de cada cabecera
        jTemp = jQuery(arrCeldas[nI]['arrHijos'][nJ]);
        arrCeldas[nI]['arrColspan'][nJ] = parseInt(jTemp.attr('colspan'));
        arrCeldas[nI]['arrRowspan'][nJ] = parseInt(jTemp.attr('rowspan'));
        if(nI>1){
            for(nK=1;nK<nCantCabeceras;nK++){
                arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'] = arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'];
                if (nI-nK>0){
                    //Recorremos las cabeceras anteriores
                    bTemp = nK==1?true:((arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][nK]<=arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][nK-1]));
                    if(bTemp){
                        if(nI-nK==1){
                            bTemp = (arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][nK]<nTemp);
                        }
                    }
                    //console.warn('nI: '+nI+' nK: '+nK+' arrLastColspan[nK='+nK+']:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][nK]+' arrLastColspan[nK-1='+(nK-1)+']:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][nK-1]);
                    if(bTemp){
                        for(nL=arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastIndex'][nK];nL<arrCeldas[nK]['nCant'];nL++){
                            if((parseInt(arrCeldas[nK]['arrRowspan'][nL])<=1) || isNaN(parseInt(arrCeldas[nK]['arrColspan'][nL]))){
                                arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastIndex'][nK] = nL + 1;
                                if(isNaN(parseInt(arrCeldas[nK]['arrColspan'][nL]))==false){
                                    if((arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][nK]<=arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastSavedColspan'][nK-1]) || (nK==1)){
                                        arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][nK] += arrCeldas[nK]['arrColspan'][nL];
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                                nL = 999999; //salimos del FOR.
                            }
                            if(nL!= 999999){
                                if(isNaN(parseInt(arrCeldas[nK]['arrColspan'][nL]))==false){
                                    if(arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][nK]<=arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastSavedColspan'][nK-1]){
                                        arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][nK] += arrCeldas[nK]['arrColspan'][nL];
                                    }
                                    nTemp += arrCeldas[nK]['arrColspan'][nL];
                                }
                            }
                            //console.warn(isNaN(parseInt(arrCeldas[nK]['arrColspan'][nL]))+':'+parseInt(arrCeldas[nK]['arrColspan'][nL])+' nI:'+nI+' nL:'+nL+' nK:'+nK+' text: '+jQuery(arrCeldas[nK]['arrHijos'][nL]).text()+' arrLastColspan[nK='+nK+']:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][nK]+' arrLastIndex[nK='+nK+']:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastIndex'][nK]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //console.warn('nI: '+nI+' nJ: '+nJ+' pre:  x:'+x+' nTemp:'+ nTemp);
            if(x<=(nTemp-1)){
                arrEncabezados[nI] = '';
                break;
                nJ = 999999; //salimos del FOR.
            }
        }
        if(nJ!= 999999){
            nTemp += arrCeldas[nI]['arrColspan'][nJ];
            if(x<=(nTemp-1)){
                for(nK=1;nK<=nCantCabeceras;nK++){
                    arrCeldas[nK]['arrLastSavedColspan'][nI] = nTemp;
                }
                arrEncabezados[nI] = jTemp.text();
                break;
                nJ = 999999; //salimos del FOR.
            }
        }
        //console.warn('nI: '+nI+' nJ: '+nJ+' post:  x:'+x+' nTemp:'+ nTemp+' text:'+jTemp.text()+' arrLastColspan [0]:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][0]+'  [1]:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][1]+' [2]:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][2]+'[3]:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastColspan'][3]+' arrLastSavedColspan [0]:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastSavedColspan'][0]+'  [1]:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastSavedColspan'][1]+' [2]:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastSavedColspan'][2]+'[3]:'+arrCeldas[nI]['arrLastSavedColspan'][3]);
    }
}
console.warn(arrEncabezados[1]+' '+arrEncabezados[2]+' '+arrEncabezados[3]+' bTemp: '+bTemp+' nCantCabeceras: '+nCantCabeceras+' Fecha:'+sFecha+' ¿se ve fecha?:'+(isScrolledVerticalIntoView(jTdFecha.get(0))&&isScrolledHorizontalIntoView(jTdFecha.get(0)))+' ¿se ve encabezado?:'+(isScrolledVerticalIntoView(jTdEncabezadoFecha.next().get(0))&&isScrolledHorizontalIntoView(jTdEncabezadoFecha.next().get(0))));

tr = '';
y = '';
x = '';
jTdFecha = '';
sFecha = '';
arrCeldas = '';
arrEncabezados = '';
arrJFila = '';
nTemp = '';
jTdEncabezadoFecha = '';
nCantCabeceras = '';
jTemp = ''; 
nI = ''; 
nJ = '';
nK = '';
nL = '';
bTemp = '';
```

})

I'm still thinking how to have detected rows with rowspans